# AWS CodeBuild - How to assign dynamic variable values in buildspec.yml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I want to name the artifact produced by my CodeBuild according to the time it was produced.

I've tried the following, but when the artifact gets uploaded to S3, the name is literally the expression, rather than the evaluated value of the expression that I've set.

Is is possible to set the env:variables to dynamic values, and if so, how? If not, is there a better way to do what I'm attempting here?

```
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    ARTIFACT_NAME: '[string]::Format("v{0}.zip", (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss"))'

... build commands ...

artifacts:
  Name:$Env:ARTIFACT_NAME
```

Update: I adjusted the artifact section to the following and omitted the variable altogether, per suggestion below, but continue to get an error when doing so.

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  discard-paths: no
  base-directory: publish/release
  name: version-$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).zip
```

Results in error:

```
[Container] 2018/08/10 15:59:26 Updating artifact name as  Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. 
Cannot convert value "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S" to type "System.DateTime". 
Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At C:\codebuild\tmp\script.ps1:5 char:21
+ echo version-$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).zip
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand

version-.zip
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax)  you can achieve that with the following syntax:

````
version: 0.2         
phases:
  build:
    commands:
     - rspec HelloWorld_spec.rb
artifacts:
  files:
   - '**/*'
  name: myname-$(date +%Y-%m-%d) ```
````

Comment: I saw that example, but it doesn't include time, only date, and I'm having trouble understanding where the value is coming from.  

I tried expanding on what was listed by including %h%m%s, but that doesn't work, so I was attempting to use the powershell format which I am more familiar with. When I include %H%M%S, the date expression doesn't seem to evaluate at all and is just omitted.  

I'm expecting to have artifacts generated several times per day, so just the date shown does not work for us.

Comment: if by value you mean the $(date +%Y-%m-%d) - that's Shell Command Language that they support.
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

is this really not working?

     ` name: myname-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)`

and how exactly is it not working?...what's the error

Comment: it might not work in the variables section, have you tried the artifacts section?...could you possibly post the example you have which is not working with extending the date with %H ?

Comment: Sure, I updated with my original artifacts section and corresponding error.

Comment: I missed the fact that it's PowerShell. I think it adhereas to .Net DateTime format then. And as far as I can see the capital S is what breaks the things here...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Try using "date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%s"

Comment: Changing the format string to one to adheres to that doesn't fix the issue, it just complains about the new format. It remains unclear to me what format it is actually expecting or how it is parsing the artifact name line.  version-$(date +%yyyy%MM%dd-%HH%mm%ss).zip is valid in Powershell, and in fact if I add a post_build that mvs the file to that location, it works. But trying to apply it to the artifact name fails the same as above.

Comment: from the error it looks like the "get-date" is executed instead of "date" ...
I just tried the online powershell editor...can you give it a last try with $(date -UFormat "%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

Comment: The -UFormat version does work within the artifact name, so I will roll with that one.  I'm not sure why it should work when appending to the documented example without the flag does not, but thank you for figuring it out!

Answer (score 1):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-6
You can try $(Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") in PowerShell.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work for you?

```
name: myname-`date '+%y%m%d-%H%M%S'`
```